# Run a file compiled in VS2012-C++ under Windows XP 64bit (SP2 only)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

If a c++ project is compiled with VS2012, using the v110_xp toolset, the file works without problems, but if the default v110 is used, then the code cannot be executed.

Is it possible to run the stuff if v110 is used. E.g. I have the vs2012 redistributable Update 4, but if e.g. Update 2 was used to compile the project, will it make any difference if I install redistributable Update 2 instead of 4?

Comment: What is "v110_xp" or "v110"?

Comment: It's the VS2012 tool set, defines in the c++ project.

Comment: Which, in case you didn't notice, you said nothing about C++

Comment: Yep, sry about that... already took a note and made the changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to target XP you must use the v110_xp toolset. The v110 toolset links to functions available only on Vista and later.

Comment: So absolutely no way to have the stuff working, even with installing VS2012 Redistributable?

Comment: Well, you'll need to install the VS2012 redist if you link to the dynamic runtime. But it is as I stated in the answer. To target you need a toolset that supports XP. And for VS2012 that is v110_xp.